# Replace all rows in a table based on date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I need to copy the values from a staging table into a production table in SQL Azure V12, considering the following rule:

> I need to replace **all rows** for a given day (see *datefield* column) in the production table with **all rows** for the same given day in the staging table provided that the extraction date/time (see *extract_datetime* column) of the rows in the staging table are newer than what is in the production table.
>
> **EDIT:** I also must include all new rows for days that don't already exist in the production table. See the purple rows in the table examples below.

The reason for this rule is that records tend to be amended and deleted from the system which we are extracting data from, so even though at one time a given day could have 200 entries for it, it might be that subsequently we only end up with 3 rows for that same given day.

If a day is included in a data extract, it will always have the most up-to-date records for that entire day (from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59 hrs).

Here is an example. Consider the following tables:
[image: example of staging and production tables]

In this example, the production table has 9 rows in total, as follows:

- 01/07/2016: 4 rows
- 02/07/2016: 2 rows
- 03/07/2016: 3 rows

Then we do a load what is in the staging table into the production table, and the following happens:

- 01/07/2016: The 4 rows in production for this day are replaced with the 1 row in the staging for this day, because what is in staging has a newer extraction date/time.
- 02/07/2016: The 2 rows in production for this day are replaced with the 4 rows in the staging for this day, because what is in staging has a newer extraction date/time.
- 03/07/2016: The 3 rows in production for this day are kept and those in the staging table are discarded, because what is in staging has an older extraction date/time.
- 07/07/2016: The 1 row in staging for this day is inserted into the production table. This is a brand new row and there is no match for it in the production table.

So in the end we end up with the following production table:

[image: example of production table after load]

These data loads are never bigger than a few megabytes, so at other tables with less complex rules what I tend to do is:

- First delete all rows in staging for when there are newer records in production;
- Delete all rows in production for when there are newer rows in staging; then
- Insert the remaining rows from staging into production, then truncate staging for the next load.

In this case I am quick lost as on how to do this matching because it is not really in a row by row basis (so I think), so any advice on how to get this code working is greatly appreciated.

Regards,
P.

Comment: EDIT: Please note the purple rows above, which were not included in the original post. New days included the staging table that don't exist in production should also be included into production.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a potential solution, just based on your sample data only, if your data sample has more complexity, such as in ONE day, you have multiple records of different extract_datetime for both prod and staging tables, we may need to find other ways (but in such scenario, your business rules may need to be modified to remove confusions, currently your business rules and your sample data are excellently matched, i.e. no confusion or grey area)

```
use tempdb
--drop table dbo.Prod, dbo.Staging, #tmp;
--go

-- create sample tables
create table dbo.Prod  (datefield datetime, field1 varchar(20), extract_datetime datetime);
create table dbo.Staging (datefield datetime, field1 varchar(20), extract_datetime datetime);
create table #tmp (datefield datetime) -- holds the deleted [DateField] value form dbo.prod

go
-- populate sample tables
insert into dbo.Prod (datefield, field1, extract_datetime) values
('20160701', 'P11', '2016-08-02 00:10:00')
,('20160701', 'P12', '2016-08-02 00:10:00')
,('20160701', 'P12', '2016-08-02 00:10:00')
,('20160701', 'P14', '2016-08-02 00:10:00')
,('20160702', 'P21', '2016-08-05 00:10:00')
,('20160702', 'P22', '2016-08-05 00:10:00')
,('20160703', 'P31', '2016-08-05 00:10:00')
,('20160703', 'P32', '2016-08-05 00:10:00')
,('20160703', 'P33', '2016-08-05 00:10:00')
go
insert into dbo.Staging (datefield, field1, extract_datetime) values
('20160701', 'S11', '2016-08-25 00:10:00')
,('20160702', 'S21', '2016-08-25 00:10:00')
,('20160702', 'S22', '2016-08-25 00:10:00')
,('20160702', 'S23', '2016-08-25 00:10:00')
,('20160702', 'S24', '2016-08-25 00:10:00')
,('20160703', 'S31', '2016-07-05 00:10:00')
,('20160703', 'S32', '2016-07-05 00:10:00')
,('20160703', 'S33', '2016-07-05 00:10:00')
,('20160703', 'S34', '2016-07-05 00:10:00')
,('20160703', 'S35', '2016-07-05 00:10:00')
,('20160707', 'S41', '2016-07-05 00:10:00') -- new record as per new requiremnt, 2016/08/15
go

-- delete records from Prod table as per business rules, but log the deleted [DateField] into #tmp for next step use
merge dbo.Prod as p
using dbo.Staging as s
on (p.DateField = s.DateField)
when matched and p.Extract_dateTime < s.Extract_datetime
then 
   delete 
output deleted.datefield into #tmp;

-- re-populate the prod table with records from staging table
insert into dbo.prod (datefield, field1, extract_datetime)
select datefield, field1, extract_datetime 
from dbo.Staging 
where Datefield in (select distinct datefield from #tmp)
or Datefield not in (select datefield from dbo.Prod) -- added as per new requirement, 2016/08/15

-- check final result
select * from dbo.prod
order by  Datefield
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this code and adapt as required. As per your point of different extract dates for one day, that is improbable and would mean a mistake during data extraction. When we extract data we extract for an entire day -- never for just a few days. So if I do an extract today (today is 10/Aug/2016) for just yesterday, all of the data rows would have the value 09/Aug/2016 in datefield and extract_datetime will have 10/Aug/2016 as the date. If my extraction is for the previous 2 days, datetime will be both 08/Aug and 09/Aug 2016 and extract_datetime will also be today (10/Aug/2016).

Comment: Do I need to add a code to drop the tmp table and have it recreated at every data load?

Comment: yes, you can drop the #tmp temp table at the end

Comment: For dropping the #tmp table in SQL Azure V12 I can do: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tmp -- otherwise if SQL Server version lower than 2016: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887011/how-to-drop-a-table-if-it-exists-in-sql-server

Comment: It would be wise to wrap it into transaction. You don't want to successfully delete some rows from `Production` and then fail to insert new rows from `Staging`.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov I know very little about transactions. How do I make sure that the transaction rolls back if there is an error?

Comment: @pmdci, you should read a book or at least [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms174377.aspx) about transactions. Usually if there is an error within a transaction (like unique constraint violation) the transaction aborts and `COMMIT` statement simply never executes; it rolls back implicitly. To gracefully handle errors there is [`TRY...CATCH`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx) in SQL Server. @jyao could show how to wrap `MERGE` and `INSERT` statements into a transaction in his answer.

Comment: Thanks @VladimirBaranov. I had a read in the MSDN article here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188929.aspx and based on what you said I believe all I need is to include a 'BEGIN TRANSACTION' and 'COMMIT TRANSACTION' since it would roll back implicitly.

Comment: Why use `merge` when all you are using it for is just deleting? Wouldn't a simple `delete` do?

Comment: Thanks for the help @jyao, but I found a little bug, for which I take the blame for as I forgot to mention that new inserts from the staging table are also a requirement even if there is no match for it in production. If I modify your code and add an additional entry at the insert for the staging table, the rows does not go into the production even though it should. For instance, try adding the following at the insertion code for the staging table: '20151224', 'S69', '2016-09-05 00:10:00') - This entry should go into production.

Comment: @pmdci, just added a new where clause in the final insert statement, hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks @jyao, the code works perfectly. One question, though: would the code be any faster if we change the staging table so it has the same extract_datetime across all rows?